# Merging rows with uniqueness constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a little time-tracking web app (implemented in Rails 3.2.8 & MySQL). The app has several users who add their time to specific tasks, on a given date. The system is set up so a user can only have 1 time entry (i.e. row) per task per date. I.e. if you add time twice on the same task and date, it'll add time to the existing row, rather than create a new one. The `user_id/task_id/date` uniqueness is enforced by a `UNIQUE` index.

Now I'm looking to merge 2 tasks. In the simplest terms, merging task ID 2 into task ID 1 would take this

```
time  | user_id  | task_id  | date
------+----------+----------+-----------
10    | 1        | 1        | 2012-10-29
15    | 2        | 1        | 2012-10-29
10    | 1        | 2        | 2012-10-29
5     | 3        | 2        | 2012-10-29
```

and change it into this

```
time  | user_id  | task_id  | date
------+----------+----------+-----------
20    | 1        | 1        | 2012-10-29 <-- time values merged (summed)
15    | 2        | 1        | 2012-10-29 <-- no change
5     | 3        | 1        | 2012-10-29 <-- task_id changed (no merging necessary)
```

I.e. merge by summing the time values, where the given user_id/date/task combo would conflict.

I figure I can use a unique constraint to do a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` if I do an insert for every task_id=2 entry. But that seems pretty inelegant.

I've also tried to figure a way to first update all the rows in task 1 with the summed-up times, but I can't quite figure that one out.

Any ideas?

---

**Update:** Going off of Olaf's answer below, I came up with this, which seems to be working

```
INSERT INTO `timetable`
(`time`, `user_id`, `task_id`, `date`)
(
    SELECT
      SUM(`time`) AS `time`,
      `user_id`,
      1 AS `task_id`,
      `date`
    FROM `timetable` AS `t1`
    WHERE `task_id` IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY `user_id`, `date`
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `time`=VALUES(`time`);

DELETE FROM `timetable` WHERE `task_id`=2;
```

I'll leave the question open in case someone has a better solution (or if there are any gotchas in my solution that I should know about)

**Update 2:** Don't know why I didn't realize this earlier, but my solution may do a lot of redundant INSERTs, because it also finds all the entries that only exist in the target task and don't need merging. In the above example data, the 2nd row will be found, re-inserted, trigger an on-duplicate-key, and set the time to the same as it already is. So if the target task has, say, 10 rows, and the source task 0 rows, it'll still do 10 (completely pointless) INSERTs.

This can be avoided by wrapping the inner SELECT everything in yet another SELECT, and use `COUNT(*)` to only find those rows that need merging. Of course, this will necessitate another more queries to update the task_id of those rows that *don't* need merging (which requires a join to figure out, as far as I can tell).

Comment: What's the criteria to merge the entries? Is it the user_id, date, anything else?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Yes, when a user_id and date combo already exists for the target task a merge should take place. I'll update my question with more fleshed-out example

Comment: How is the key defined for your table?

Comment: @OlafDietsche ```UNIQUE KEY `uniqueness` (`user_id`,`date`,`task_id`)```- and I apologize that I wasn't clear about that in my question the first time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing on `user_id` and `date` would be:

```
select sum(time), user_id, 1, date
from timetable
group by user_id, date;
```

Updating the time table (kudos to @Flambino):

```
insert into timetable (time, user_id, task_id, date)
    select sum(time), user_id, 1, date
    from timetable
    group by user_id, date
on duplicate key update time = values(time);
```

And finally remove all rows with `task_id` not 1:

```
delete from timetable where task_id > 1;
```

When updates are restricted to tasks 1 and 2, apply where clause like in @Flambino's update.

Comment: Seems like a good way to go except I have multiple tasks, and I only want to merge 2 at a time. I.e. I'm guessing there should be some extra where-clauses in there (and the delete statement should certainly be more precise)

Comment: @Flambino Ok, I just wanted to flesh out the basic approach, but this doesn't work yet.

Comment: Yeah, I see you updating your answer - thanks for taking the time!

Comment: I think I found a good solution using ON DUPLICATE - very much thanks to your answer. I'll add my own solution to my question, but I'll leave the question open in case you find an even neater solution